# How to detect if close button was pressed in a wx.FileDialog?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

> How can i evaluate if a user pressed the `Close Window` button in a
>   `wx.fileDialog` while opening a file?

i have 2 textboxes...
one is for showing the input filepath
and the other is to show the output filepath

the `output` depends on the `input filepath`, since the `output filepath` is gonna be the same directory of the input, but with a different name.

sometimes the user `opens the filepath and press the close button`...
and that action generates a `outfile` equals to `_edited.txt` but that shouldn't happen.

i wanna something like

```
if user_action == press_the_close_button:
    outfile = ""
else:
    outfile = infile_edited.txt
```

how can i fix that?

I'm using:
**Py 2.7.9** and **wx 3.0.2.0**

> the openFile function

```
def abrirArquivo(self, event):
        try:
            #open fileDialog box
            openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "", "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt", wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
            openFileDialog.ShowModal()

            #get the filepath
            infile = openFileDialog.GetPath()
            #change the inputTxtCtrl to the filepath
            self.inputTxtCtrl.SetValue(infile)

            #if user dont select any file in the fileDialog, how can i evaluate it and correctly so it doesnt change the outfileTextBox
            if infile == "":
                #change textLabel to "File not selected.."
                self.textoProgresso.SetLabel("File wasn't loaded properly...")
            else:
                #create output filepath
                outfile = infile[0:len(str(infile))-4] + "_edited.txt"
                #change outputTxtCtrl to the outfile filepath
                self.outputTxtCtrl.SetValue(outfile)
                #change progress bar to 10%
                self.barraProgresso.SetValue(10)
                #change textLabel to "File found.."
                self.textoProgresso.SetLabel("File loaded in the system...")
        except Exception:
            print "error_abrir_arquivo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the return from wxFileDialog::ShowModal.  It will be wxID_OK if the user pressed OK, and wxID_CANCEL otherwise.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_dialog.html#a04943e4abb27a197a110898d40ddb4f0

Answer (score 0):

as of wxPython 2.8.11 you can use the context manager.

```
with wx.FileDialog(self,
                   message='Choose file to open',
                   defaultDir=wx.GetHomeDir(),
                   defaultFile='evaluation.doc',
                   style=wx.FD_OPEN|wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as dlgF:
    fdRet = dlgF.ShowModal()
    if fdRet == wx.ID_OK:
        fileName = dlgF.GetPath()
        # do something with the file e.g.
        desktop.open(fileName)
    elif fdRet == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        # optional handling of cancel button
        pass
```

This will ensure that the FileDialog will be destroyed without you having to worry about, by checking the return code "wx.ID_OK" and by using the style "wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST" you know that a file was selected.  If you need a special handling of the cancel dialog you can do that with an 'elif'.